# How to execute bash command using sudo with scp?

Tags: sudo

For example, in `sudo -l` i discovery that I can run scp through sudo with Makulele user. I would like to know how to execute a bash command using scp. 
Example:

```
sudo -u makulele scp executeBASHcommandASmakulele
```

Maybe using `-S` option or `-p` with suid flag as well... Does anyone have a way to do this?

Comment: You could use scp to copy a setuid binary and change the user, then you can execute the copied file to obtain the setuid privilege.

Comment: scp doesnt support execution of comands...https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp

Comment: wireghoul catch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scp` [doesn't execute commands](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp). I'm not entirely sure why you think it should.

Perhaps you want to run `executeBASHcommandASmakulele` on the local system as the `makulele` user:

```
sudo -u makulele executeBASHcommandASmakulele
```

Or if it's a script/program in the current directory,

```
sudo -u makulele ./executeBASHcommandASmakulele
```

Or perhaps you want to run  `executeBASHcommandASmakulele` on a remote system as the `makulele` user:

```
sudo -u makulele ssh remote_host executeBASHcommandASmakulele
```

Comment: in that case the only option I had was to execute commands by scp

Comment: You can't execute commands through scp. If that's what you think you were doing, you weren't.

Comment: In hack.me had a challenge that you need to scape from a chroot jail and one level of this jail was the 'scp' as the only disponible command. Whatever, I'm not doing hack.me challenges anymore. Thanks a lot for the reply.